# Como puedo mostrar el valor de un elemento Local Storage en el Dom

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual pues no es mio, cuento con poco conocimiento en Javascript, sin embargo si se que este código lanza una especie de *Array* en el *LocalStorage*, lo que quisiera hacer es mostrar en el DOM únicamente el nombre para poder poner Bienvenido y el nombre del usuario.
Lo que esta guardado en el Storage es como valor es  `{name: "Angelo", contact: "85002011", addr: "San Antonio} addr1: "San Antonio" contact: "85002011" name: "Angelo"`  y la llave es = (adress)

el codigo que tengo es el siguiente

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   try {
       if (localStorage.adress) {
           waddr = JSON.parse(localStorage.adress);
           document.getElementById('elname').value = waddr.name;
           document.getElementById('elmobile').value = waddr.contact;
           document.getElementById('eladdress').value = waddr.addr;
           updateEladdress();

       }
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
   }
});
```

Comment: Intente hacerlo con esto


 ```  var nombre = window.localStorage.getItem('adress');
                            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = nombre; ``` 


pero me lanza todo el array que esta guardado ademas de los corchetes

Comment: Hola @Benito-B ¿Podrias intentar ser mas amable al pedir información sobre una pregunta?

Comment: Para usuarios nuevos puede ser intimidante recibir este tipo de respuestas, no es genial hacer preguntas pasivo agresivas como '¿y como pretendes?' puede resultar ofensivo y retante.

Comment: @AngeloAguilar Si ya editaste tu pregunta lo puedes aclarar en el comentario en lugar de repetir el edit, esto es para que quien quiera ayudarte obtenga el contexto completo de nuevo :D un saludo.

Comment: Hola @Benito-B Lo que esta guardado en el Storage es como valor es  ```{name: "Angelo", contact: "85002011", addr: "San Antonio}
 ``` y la llave es = (adress)

Comment: @Benito-B Te comento que hay maneras para llevar amenamente los comentarios de una pregunta siendo cordial. Y en lugar de retar o ridiculizar la situación, podrias invitar al usuario a que por favor edite su pregunta con la información necesaria correspondiente. Cierro el hilo, un saludo.

Comment: Hola...esque la otra vez que puse muchos detalles me corrigieron que debía ser mas simple ...entonces no se ...tambien en ocaciones me dijeron que editara la pregunta y pues ya ni idea ...en fin no pasa nada. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Lo que debes hacer es añadir un evento cuando cargue tu página web. A partir de ahí haces un llamado a localStorage para obtener la información del usuario y poder colocarla en un elemento del DOM.

De esta manera, con este código HTML y JS, podrás mostrar la información del usuario si se encuentra en localStorage.

**NOTA:** Para fines de la demo, yo creo el objeto en localStorage la primera vez que carga la página. Pero yo supongo que ésta información va venir de un API o previamente ya estará almacenada en respuesta a alguna función.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Documento de prueba para javascript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="user-name">Hola</h1>
    <script src="./sample.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

y tu Javascript:

```javascript
function getUserInformation() {
  const userInformation = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInformation"));
  if (!userInformation) {
    localStorage.setItem(
      "userInformation",
      JSON.stringify({
        name: "Jhon",
        lastname: "Doe",
        adress: "No Doe Address",
      })
    );
  }

  const h1Element = document.querySelector(".user-name");

  h1Element.textContent = `Hola ${userInformation.name}`;
}

window.addEventListener("load", getUserInformation);
```

Comment: WOW Exelente muchas gracias , funciono pèrfectamente